# Laravel and Blade - how to write a variable inside quotes?

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

I am trying to produce something like

```
id="checkout-button-{someid}"
```

For instance

```
id="checkout-button-jjn5jghj5"
```

I thought this would be done through unescaped strings doing this

```
id={!! "checkout-button-$item->id" !!}
```

But this is not producing the variable in the string.

What is proper way to do this in blade views?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Blade is going to

1. Look for the opening `{{`
2. Capture everything before the closing `}}`, and then
3. Evaluate the expression and use that value to replace the entire `{{ ... }}` string

In your case, the only thing you need Blade for is getting the `id`. So your statement should look like this:

`id="checkout-button-{{ $item->id }}"`